# Аналог Union Types(TypeScript) в C#?

Tags: c#, union

Как в C# объявить тип подобный [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#defining-a-union-type) из TypeScript?

```
type OnlyOne = "one" | "two" | "three"

function foo(value: OnlyOne) {
  // ...
}

foo("two") // Ok
foo("error") // Error => Argument of type '"error"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OnlyOne'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=101&pln=4&pc=1#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgO6oHSQJ4wKZwMYBOAljJADYCGAdgOZoD2htwAJg-nMODawEYMGAa2AAmYDgBuOQplaVMAWiy44aKAFtyAYlY4AZsWpHaiyooCuxhtWXYcAWABQKnKADy1cpk9uAvKAARDY4gaAAPkGQyAxhkYGQ4IQ4oc7O+lb4kMQ2oPqCABSSlOQWOAgeXj7UOACUoADezqCgIKBoHc4AvmlO+QwFCTGBtemFgTKETCOtYACihFOEoH4AfKAAgswWGjjUkKAM+qCuoADkE4vTZ6DEcKDUDAeUcHDEtNSUfORukAygMEohEou0gMkOx1OZ083l8ZyAA)

Базовый тип предполагается один (например `string` или `int`), но значения, которые он может содержать, должны быть константными.

Т.е. что-то вроде такого:

```cs
void fun((string: "foo"|"bar") str) {}
fun("bar") // => Ok
fun("some") // => Error
```

Comment: в c# эти union'ы просто не нужны, т.к. там строгая типизация. если же вы хотите строгой проверки, например, чтобы входной параметр должен быть в диапазоне определённых значений, то в c# это делается `if`'ами, т.е. во время runtime'а. если вы хотите проверять во время компиляции, то смотрите в сторону erlang или чего-то такого

Comment: Пока не завезли в C# поддержку discriminated union :( https://habr.com/en/company/jugru/blog/503868/

Comment: @return Речь не о нарушении типизации, а как раз о константных значениях некоторого базового типа. Я предполагал, что можно обернуть тип во что-то похожее на `enum`, или применить какие-то атрибуты методам. ... и проверять `EnumDataContainer` константных значений на этапе компиляции.

Comment: @AK Очень жаль. Я надеюсь, что ответ кроется где-то здесь [Атрибуты](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/).

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg я вам уже сказал, что если вы хотите сделать то, о чём вы написали в комменте выше, вам не сюда

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg атрибуты не питоновские декораторы

Comment: Тут уже написали, что такого в C# пока нет, повторяться не буду. Отмечу лишь, что много лет сообщество ждёт, надеется, верит... От себя дополню: можете погуглить _монады_, особенно Maybe monad - есть много статей, описывающих их реализацию в C#. Это близко к тому, что вы хотите. / Атрибуты не помогут сделать то, что вы хотите. Атрибуты в .NET содержат _метаданные_, они не содержат _выполняемый код_.

Comment: Чисто теоретически, у нас уже есть возможность реализовать вашу хотелку: написать Roslyn-анализатор кода, который будет прямо в IDE проверять типы. Но это очень сложно и проверка будет работать лишь при подключенном анализаторе. То есть он должен быть установлен у всех членов команды, а также на билд-сервере.

Comment: @return _в c# эти union'ы просто не нужны(с)_ - Вот целая масса людей так не считает. Посмотрите мой ответ, может найдете для себя что-нибудь интересное.

Comment: @AK Спасибо за терминологию `discriminated union`, это помогло выйти на одну библиотеку, которая как раз эмулирует `Union`.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg как бы, `'a' | 'b'` не тоже самое, что и tagged unions

Answer (score 2):

Подобные вопросы, как оказалось, рассматриваются несколько лет.

Ссылки по теме:

- [Discriminated unions / enum class](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/discriminated-unions.md).
- [issues: Discriminated Unions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/113).
- [А тут как раз началось с Typescript: Union и Intersection](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/399)

Цитата из последнего комментария:

> "...они значительно упростят представление данных без чрезмерного злоупотребления наследованием."(c)

... как раз чрезмерное наследование, мне и показалось излишним.

Самое интересное [здесь: OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf).

В примере ниже, метод принимает разнородные типы, не имеющие общего интерфейса, а `OneOf` возвращает обобщенный тип.

```
// Пихаем все в один НЕперегруженный метод, в точности как на TypeScript.
PrintAsHex((50, 150, 250));
PrintAsHex(EnumColor.Red);
PrintAsHex(new ClassColor());

// Без перегрузки выглядит намного лучше.
void PrintAsHex(MultiTypeColor mtc) {
  // а здесь мы уже работаем с MultiTypeColor
}
```

Нерабочий сниппет:

```js
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using OneOf;

namespace DiscriminatedUnions {
  class Program {
    static void Main() {
      // Ну разве это не здорово
      Some.PrintAsHex((50, 150, 250));
      Some.PrintAsHex(EnumColor.Red);
      Some.PrintAsHex(new ClassColor());
      // Some.PrintAsRGB(new Some()); // А тут неизвестный тип => Error CS1503
    }
  }

  class Some {
    // В теле метода имеем нужный нам тип
    public static void PrintAsHex(MultiTypeColor mtc) {
      Console.WriteLine(mtc.Hex);
    }
  }

  enum EnumColor {
    Red,
    Blue
  }

  class ClassColor {
    public byte R = 10;
    public byte G = 20;
    public byte B = 30;
  }

  // Если не обращать внимания на это безобразие, выше все выглядит достаточно прилично.
  class MultiTypeColor : OneOfBase<(byte, byte, byte), EnumColor, ClassColor> {
    Func<string, string> get = v => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(KnownColor), v) ? v : "White";
    public Color Color { get; private set; }
    public string Hex { get => $"#{Color.R:X2}{Color.G:X2}{Color.B:X2}"; }
    MultiTypeColor(OneOf<(byte, byte, byte), EnumColor, ClassColor> _) : base(_) {
      Color = _.Index switch {
        0 => Color.FromArgb(_.AsT0.Item1, _.AsT0.Item2, _.AsT0.Item3),
        1 => Color.FromName(get(_.AsT1.ToString())),
        2 => Color.FromArgb(_.AsT2.R, _.AsT2.G, _.AsT2.B),
        _ => Color.FromName("White")
      };
    }
    public static implicit operator MultiTypeColor((byte, byte, byte) _) => new(_);
    public static implicit operator MultiTypeColor(EnumColor _) => new(_);
    public static implicit operator MultiTypeColor(ClassColor _) => new(_);
  }
}
```

... а здесь рабочий [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ehc1Zk)

Типизацию мы не нарушаем:

- При вызове метода уже известны возможные типы.
- В теле имеем тип параметра. *Очень печалит отсутствие implicit operator в Typescript*.

Я предполагал, что подобное встроено в язык, но видимо придется немного подождать.

Comment: Здорово! Однако, насколько я понимаю, это проверка по _типу_. Отличить значения `"one" | "two" | "three"` не получится - они все типа `string`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, со строкой видимо не получится, но она легко заменяется `enum`. К слову в TypeScript, строка считается константой, если явно передана в параметр, с переменной она бы тоже не сработала. Мне почему-то казалось, что такой вариант манипуляции с типами параметров, должен быть по дефолту в C#.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я только сейчас сообразил, почему все предлагают какие-то if-ы в рантайм. В моем примере нет ни одной строки, но все воспринимают это строками. [Вот пример как воспринимает литералы TypeScript - это и есть типы](https://clck.ru/XkiMK).

Comment: В C# очень бедная система типов. Поэтому извращаются кто как может. Большинство используют рантайм-проверки и даже не подозревают, что в других языках это же можно делать в компайл-тайме. Эх... Моя плакать по Nemerle...

Answer (score 1):

```
class FUN
{
    public static string[] filter;
    public static void SetFilter(params string[] filter) => FUN.filter = filter;
    public void Fun(string str)
    {
        if (!(FUN.filter?.Contains(str) ?? true))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        ///
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
FUN.SetFilter("foo", "bar");
new FUN().Fun("foo"); //foo
new FUN().Fun("some"); //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Можно улучшить, передавая в FUN() ссылку на функцию, которую нужно выполнить после .Fun("foo"), которая будет выполняться вместо Console.WriteLine

Так-же можно отказаться от статического поля и будет выглядеть примерно так:
`FUN fun1 = new FUN(Action<> action, params string[] filter)`
А вызывать через:
`fun1.Call(string str);`
Тогда при FUN() вы создаёте объект с вызываемой функцией и фильтром, а при Call() фильтруете и если всё ок - выполняете функцию.

Пример кода:

```
//описание класса, выполняющего Action
class FUN
{
    string[] filter;
    Action action;
    public FUN(Action action, params string[] filter)
    {
        this.action = action;
        this.filter = filter;
    }
    public void Call(string str)
    {
        if (!(filter.Contains(str)) && filter.Length != 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        ///
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
//функция, которая должна выполняться
void myMethod(object a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
//упаковка Action (можно переделать и упростить)
Action myAction = () => myMethod(123);
//создание вызываемого экземпляра с функцией и фильтром
FUN fun1 = new FUN(myAction, "foo", "bar");
//вызов с фильтрацией
fun1.Call("foo"); //123
//вызов с фильтрацией
fun1.Call("some"); //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Есть ещё вариант с цепочкой вызываемых функций/методов, суть в том что в первом вы вызываете проверку, а в последующих выполняется код:

```
//описываете делегат (контейнер функций/методов)
delegate void FilterCall(string str);
//создаёте конкретный экземпляр
FilterCall filtercall;
//описываете функцию проверки
void filtermethod(string str)
{
    if (!(new string[] { "foo","bar" }.Contains(str)))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
//добавляете функцию проверки
filtercall += filtermethod;
//описываете полезную функцию
void myMethod(string str)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Вызов myMethod с параметром: " + str);
}
//добавляете полезную функцию
filtercall += myMethod;
filtercall("foo"); //Вызов myMethod с параметром: foo
filtercall("some"); //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Для разных типов:

```
class FUN<T>
{
    T[] filter;
    Action action;
    public FUN(Action action, params T[] filter)
    {
        this.action = action;
        this.filter = filter;
    }
    public void Call(T str)
    {
        if (!(filter.Contains(str)) && filter.Length != 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        ///
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
FUN<int> fun1 = new FUN<int>(myAction, 1, 2);
fun1.Call(1); //123 т.к. в myMethod выше так и записали, можно принимать конкретное значение
fun1.Call(3); //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Проверка на тип:

```
class FUN
{
    Type[] filter;
    Action action;
    public FUN(Action action, params Type[] filter)
    {
        this.action = action;
        this.filter = filter;
    }
    public void Call<T>(T data)
    {
        if (!(filter.Contains(data.GetType())) && filter.Length != 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        ///
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
FUN fun1 = new FUN(myAction, typeof(int), typeof(string));
fun1.Call("123"); //123
fun1.Call(123); //123
fun1.Call(123.0); //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException т.к. тип double
struct MyStruct { }
MyStruct ms = new MyStruct();
fun1.Call(ms); //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException т.к. тип опять неподходящий
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
fun1.Call(now); //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException и время тоже не принимает
fun1.Call(int.Parse("123")); //123
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я нашел эмуляцию того о чем шла речь. Посмотрите мой ответ.
Не понимаю, почему мне никто не подсказал название уже давно имеющегося OneOf :(.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg потому-что OneOf нестандартный, и число типов ограничено 8-9 единицами, не все знают, да и не всем это нужно, проще и быстрее своё решение закостылить.

Comment: Типов там больше > 20, не помню точно но ночью сегодня читал, хотя их и 10-ти с головой хватает. А свое "закостылить", может и лучше, если'б я все все знал, так и вопросов бы не было.

Comment: 20 одновременно используемых? И кстати, что там с интерфейсами и наследованием? Если вы проверите что List<int> проходит ли фильтр на соответствие IEnumerable<int> - пройдёт проверку? Сомневаюсь.

Comment: Да, на счет 20 я что-то не то прочитал, 2-ой день без сна, можно что угодно напутать.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать новый тип, который будет содержать проверку, при преобразовании из старого, а преобразовывать с помощью implicit.
Пример:

```
public class OneTwoString{
    public string Value{get;}

    public OneTwoString(string value){
    //валидация строки, типа:
    if (value == "One" || value == "Two")
    {
          Value = value;
    }else{
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    }
    public static implicit operator OneTwoString(string value) => new OneTwoString(value);
}

public clsas Program{
    public void Main(){
      var value = "One";
      SomeMethod("One"); // отработает
      value = "Ten";
      SomeMethod(value); // ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    }

    public void SomeMethod(OneTwoString value){
      // value.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Речь скорее о [чем-то подобном в F#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions), о чем упомянул @_A-K в комменте. Но за ответ спасибо.

Comment: Тут осуществляется проверка в рантайме. А нужно в компайлтайме.

Comment: ага. Про то, что в C# это никак не сделать - уже написано. Еще как вариант, опять таки используя строгую типизацию, просто использовать перегрузку методов, определить SomeMethod(string some) , SomeMethod(int some). Писанины будет много, но при вызове метода - это будет похоже на UnionTypes

Comment: @AlexanderBrattsev _Про то, что в C# это никак не сделать - уже написано(с)_ комментарий может не всегда соответствовать истине. Кстати, библиотека, в теперь уже "самоответе"(см. ответ), как раз и использует `implicit`, но оборачивает все типы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov _написать Roslyn-анализатор кода(c)_ Уже ничего писать не надо, за нас все написали. См. ответ.